# How can I login to Facebook from my background job?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want to regularly post updates to my company's Facebook page using a timer task. In order to post to a facebook page I need to obtain a user (page) access token. In order to obtain a user access token I need to login to Facebook on behalf of a user.

How can I login to Facebook programmatically with some user's email and password from a background job without clicking on any UI?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically get an user access token through Facebook Graph API. User access token could only be retrieved by login flow.

In your situation, you can consider using an [extended (long-lived) access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension/).